# input fields not responding to display flex

Tags: html, css

I have a set of input fields that look like so:

```css
.input-set {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-set">
  <div class="group-1">
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
  </div>

  <div class="group-2">
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
  </div>

  <div class="group-3">
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the set of three inputs fields are still showing horizontally. I have added `display: flex;` to the groupings of inputs and it is still showing horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

Inputs won't be affected by display flex, because they aren't direct children on flex element. For inputs to respond flex layout, add display flex to group-1, group-2, group-3

Comment: To be clear I am wanting for each group to be vertically aligned, not just the inputs themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the `.group-n` div (parent of input) to show vertically? If that's the case, add `flex-direction: column;` into your `.input-set` class.